# Match image name with database records

Tags: php

i've got the following problem:

I have some images in a folder and a sql database record.I have fetch all images from folder and we

match that image name with having the field in the database.if these are same then we have to

rename that image with the another name.

My problem is how to create a log file and insert the record to log file either there are any match

or not.

```
<?php

define("BASE_IMAGE_PATH", "D:\\");
define("IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME", "2014finalfour\\");
define("IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME_MODIFIED", "modified\\");
define("IMAGE_File_Path", BASE_IMAGE_PATH . IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME);
define("IMAGE_File_Path_Modified", BASE_IMAGE_PATH . IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME . IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME_MODIFIED);
ini_set("display_error", 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
$srcdir  = constant("IMAGE_File_Path");
$destdir = constant("IMAGE_File_Path_Modified");

if (!file_exists(IMAGE_File_Path_Modified)) {
    mkdir(IMAGE_File_Path_Modified, 0777, true);
}

$conn      = odbc_connect('NCAA', 'sa', '12345');
$query     = "Select ImageID,Zoho_ID from UDFields where ImageID IS NOT NULL ";
$resa      = odbc_exec($conn, $query);
$image_id  = array();
$full_name = array();
$zoho_id   = array();

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($resa)) {
    $zoho_id[]  = $row['Zoho_ID'];
    $image_id[] = $row['ImageID'];
}

$srcdire = opendir($srcdir);

for ($j = 0; $j < count($zoho_id); $j++) {
    $full_name[$j] = $zoho_id[$j] . '_' . $image_id[$j];
}

while ($readFile = readdir($srcdire)) {
    if ($readFile != '.' && $readFile != '..') {
        if (!file_exists($readFile)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($image_id); $i++) {
                if ($readFile == $image_id[$i]) {
                    copy($srcdir . $readFile, $destdir . $full_name[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "Export Successfully";
closedir($srcdir);
odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

Please Help me to sought out it.

Comment: you really need to learn how to format code properly ... both at stackoverflow and production

Answer (score 0):

Use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php) with `FILE_APPEND` flag to manage a log file. For example:

```
if (image in database) {
    file_put_contents($log_filename, "Image was found\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
} else {
    file_put_contents($log_filename, "Image was NOT found\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

The `LOCK_EX` flag is here to protect concurrent accesses to the file (e.g.,different client request at the same time).